# Exporting a static function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a class defined in  headerfile x.h in dll-1 which is

---

```
class A{
   public:
   static int val;
__declspec(dllexport) static void setval(int v) {val = v;} 
};
```

---

and x.cpp has

---

```
int A::val = 256;
```

---

Now I built dll-1 and it went through, but the other dlls that link this dll failed to build with error unresolved external symbol **public: static int A::val** . This got resolved when I defined the exported function in x.cpp. but I don't understand why it broke. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting static data in a DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479784/exporting-static-data-in-a-dll)

Comment: Did you get [Compiler Warning (level 1) C4251](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esew7y1w.aspx)? That page quite ***explicitely*** mentions _`All your static data is access through functions that are exported from the DLL`_. In the future, you will want [to include the compiler error (like I mentioned before you posted here, incidentally)](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=5507868#5507868)  <whistle/>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you defined the function inline, the compiler is free to create a copy of the function in the places you call it from. Those copies are unable to see the variable because it wasn't exported.

When you move the function definition to the .cpp then all calls go back to the DLL, which could resolve the variable when the DLL was created.

Comment: That sounds about right. I couldn't exactly get my finger on it. +1