# C++ dllimport: unresolved externals with static fields

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dllimport, dllexport

I have a Visual Studio C++ project containing main program and a DLL module.
The DLL has a class with the following definition:

```
// .h
#ifdef _USRDLL
    #define DLLAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLLAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLAPI EClass
{
public:
    static int value;

    static int get_value();
};

// .cpp
int EClass::value = 1;

int EClass::get_value()
{
    return value;
}
```

The DLL project is compiled successfully, both symbols (value and get_value) are observable by Dependency Walker.

In the main program, I can call the static function `get_value`

```
int v = EClass::get_value();  // Ok, v = 1
```

but when I try to access the field `value` directly

```
int v = EClass::value;  // Error
```

I get an error

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static int EClass::value" (?value@EClass@@2HA)
```

It is possible to avoid using accessors for static fields?

Comment: Look like you not exporting the static, did you try to add `DLLAPI`  before its declaration? (for outside the class)

Comment: maybe also need to add to the header: `extern DLLAPI int EClass::value;` to tell your app to dllimport it.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with no success.
The static field is exported correctly: I have an access to it using the accessor method and I see this field in DLL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting static data in a DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479784/exporting-static-data-in-a-dll)

Comment: @AndreyNasonov Are you using your dll from other dll? if so your usage of the `_USRDLL` macro instead of a unique macro for each dll may cause the problem, anyway, for a single dll and a single exe using it, it works for me without any change on my visual studio 10 express.

Comment: Thank you for the right way. The problem was `_USRDLL` macro defined in both DLL and EXE project configurations. I have no idea how this was happened. Now it's all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The macro `_USRDLL` should be defined only in the DLL project.