# Are static class methods and variables visible form different modules (libs, dlls, exes)?

Tags: c++, static, global

The case is quite simple - we had a discussion based on experiencing some linker issues, where colleagues of mine were stating, that we are unable to access the static methods and variables that are declared and defined within the **class**, from other modules (dlls, libs, exe).

I believe it is **not** the case and this rule applies just for static **global** methods (if you do not export them manually), that are not visible, as the linker tries to persevere the ODR.

Who is correct, are static class methods/vars really invisible or this applies just for global statics?

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15235526/10871073)

Comment: They are accessible when exported correctly (dllexport on windows). However exporting static member variables (globals) do come with their own initialization issues. So I would not recommend doing that.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Yep, but that is the case of the global ones (that you need to alter the visibility rules for linker), with the ones declared within class you do not need to perform any exporting magic I believe.

Comment: There can be problems with inline static methods accessing static member variable.
See [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479784/exporting-static-data-in-a-dll),  the accepted answer and some other answers. Making the method not inline or giving it its own dllexport/dllimport attribute (in addition to common class-level dllexport) helps in most of the cases.